# Catching base Exception to preserve data integrity

Tags: exceptions, data, error-handling

I know that often catching all exceptions (C#: `catch(Exception exception){...}`) is deemed bad practice.

However, I believe that there are situations where it is perfectly reasonable to do it. For example, if I have a number of operations to perform:

```
foreach(var operation in operationBatch)
    operation.Do();
```

and a batch should either succeed as a whole, or fail as a whole, does this seem reasonable?

```
var rollBackStack = new Stack<Operation>(operationBatch.Length);
try{
  foreach(var operation in operationBatch)
  {
      operation.Do();
      rollBackStack.Push(operation); // assuming operation is atomic and cannot both apply changes AND fail
  }
} catch(Exception exception) // whatever went wrong...
{
    foreach(var ranOperation in rollBackStack)
      ranOperation.Undo();

    throw; // or throw new MyDomainException("relevant message", exception);
}
```

I guess a generic version of the question would be: is catching all exceptions only to perform some action and rethrowing an acceptable practice, or is there another way that's recommended? I can think of something like

```
var completed = 0;
try{
  foreach(var operation in operationBatch)
  {
      operation.Do();
      ++completed;
  }
} finally {
    if(completed != operationBatch.Length)
        foreach(var ranOperation in operationBatch.Take(completed).Reverse())
          ranOperation.Undo();

    // no need to rethrow from finally
}
```

But this seems like simply unnecessarily more complex version of the first snippet.

Comment: Your first version is pefectly OK. You know you can't complete the whole operationsList, so you roll back. That's a perfectly legal reason for catching an exception, doing something and re-throwing because your caller needs to know that the batch didn't execute.

Comment: I've said it before: [Don't get hung on CA1031](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264977/6559) - it's a very incomplete rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're OK.

From the documentation for [CA1031](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> **CA1031: Do not catch general exception types**
>
> **Cause**
>
> A general exception such as System.Exception or System.SystemException is caught in a catch statement, or a general catch clause such as catch() is used.
>
> **How to Fix Violations**
>
> To fix a violation of this rule, catch a more specific exception, ***or rethrow the general exception as the last statement in the catch block.***

It seems the guidance on this particular rule is that it is OK to catch a general exception as long as you rethrow it. Your design is consistent with this guidance.

Note: There is a signficant difference between these two statements:

```
throw; 

throw new MyDomainException("relevant message", exception);
```

In most cases you should use the former, which preserves the stack trace and original exception type so that "outer" catch blocks can distinguish between a system error like out of memory (which they usually will not want to catch, since they can't really handle them) and domain exceptions (which they probably can).